# How to invoke default behavior in jQuery valHooks?

Tags: jquery, valhooks

This question explains valHooks [What are jQuery valHooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731153/what-are-jquery-valhooks) .

In some situation, I'd like to just intercept behavior of `$.val()`. That is, inject some functionality, and then invoke the default behavior of `val()`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just return `undefined`.

`valHooks` is apparently not documented on jQuery's site so I guess it's all unofficial and may change but in the meantime ...

I actually wanted to modify the value between the user entering it and the webapp reading it and the blog post I found about `valHooks` didn't tell me to return my new value so by default my debug `console.log` printed but otherwise the app was unaffected.

So this should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how to call custom code when `.val()` is called to set the value of a `<select>` element:

```
(function() {
    var origValHooksSelectSet = $.valHooks.select.set;

    $.valHooks.select.set = function(select, value) {
        var result = origValHooksSelectSet.call(this, select, value);

        // Custom code goes here.

        return result;
    };
})();
```

The `origValHooksSelectSet` variable refers to the original function, so it can be called in the new function. Everything is wrapped in an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) just so the `origValHooksSelectSet` variable is not global, but can still be used in the new function as a closure variable.